# JSON trouble to geting value

Tags: python, json

I have a fragment of network device configuration in json format, with the previous fragments I had no problem to extract information. However, I have a problem with this. Can I ask for advice?I know that in the last part of the append function I have an error because there I need to get the key, not the value:

```
 "policy": [
      {
         "from-zone-name": "admin",
         "to-zone-name": "Switches",
         "policy": [
            {
               "name": "admin-Switches",
               "match": {
                  "source-address": [
                     "any"
                  ],
                  "destination-address": [
                     "any"
                  ],
                  "application": [
                     "any"
                  ]
               },
               "then": {
                  "permit": [
                     "None"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
```

```
data = self.dev.rpc.get_config(filter_xml='security',
                                       options={'format': 'json'})
        self.policies = data['configuration']['security']['policies']['policy']
        for i in self.policies:
            self.data.append([i['from-zone-name'],
                              i['to-zone-name'],
                              i['policy']['name'],
                              i['policy']['match']['source-address'],
                              i['policy']['match']['destination-address'],
                              i['policy']['match']['application'],
                              i['policy']['then'].keys()])
        print(self.data)
```

error code:

```
    i['policy']['name'],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: policy is an object array, and u needs to go with 
i['policy'][index]['name']

Comment: oh damn was it that trivial? As I understand it, I can easily put [0] there, since I don't plan to have 2 different policies for one from zone to zone